# User earnings not going higher

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok so I am storing users earnings that they have made inside my database I have the column set has decimal`(5,5)`.
It seems that as soon as the value hits `0.99999` it will not go any higher, for example over to `1.00000`.

I am doing a simple update

```
  $fdfsdfdsfsdf = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET available_earning=available_earning+0.00002 WHERE id  = '".$owner2."'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

The update works in till the earnings get up to `0.99999` then stops. Any idea's what I can do ?

Comment: Please prepare SQL queries properly: yours is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: You should refrain from using `mysql_query` as it is being deprecated in PHP. Take a look at PDO or MySQLi for the new drivers in PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> decimal(5,5)

This definition allows only 5 digits and 5 are reserved for decimals, so `0.99999` is max what you can put in it.

[Read more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html) about datatypes in mysql

Comment: so i have to change it to 5.2 ? wouldn't tht show has 5 numbers and then . then 2 numbers ?

Comment: You need to adjust it to your needs, `5,2` is only example in the manual.

Comment: I need the result to be max of 000.99999

Comment: `(5,2)` would have  column range from `-999.99 to 999.99`

Comment: @user2442903 user `(8,5)` I guess

Comment: so i would have to use 6,3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `(8,5)` instead of `(5,5)`

```
(5,2) would have column range from -999.99 to 999.99
```